# When Setting Up ApolloGraphQL Persisted Queries, How To Support /GraphQL?

Tags: react-apollo, apollo-client, apollo-server

When I follow the ApolloGraphQL docs here:

https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/performance/apq/#setup

It says that the Apollo Server automatically handles AQP requests with no changes.  Yet, when my client calls:

http://localhost:4000/graphql

I get a 404 file not found.

Shouldn't that automatically be working on an apollo graphql server?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't realize for localhost testing I need to set full uri.

```js
const link = ApolloLink.from([
  createPersistedQueryLink({ useGETForHashedQueries: true }),
  createHttpLink({ uri: "http://localhost:4000/graphql" })
]);
```